# How to know when an item is added to a sortable container in jQuery Sortable UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to use [Sortable Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) to create a [connect list](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) where I have two containers one with available items and the other one where to drop items into.

I need to be able to do something when the item is moved from the left container to the right container.

This is my code to create both containers.

I tried to capture `change` event but that does not tell me if the item was added or not.

```
    $( "#sortable").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable_1"
    });

    $( "#selected_sortable").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable_1",
        change: function(e,i){
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

What event can I fire to figure if the Item was moved from the left container to the right container?

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive

Comment: Thank you so much. That is exactly what I am looking for. Please post an answer and I will be glad to accept it.

Comment: I've added an answer

Answer (score 0):

You want to listen for the [receive](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) event of Sortable.

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "sortreceive", function( event, ui ) {} );
```